# Can a body do SHM (Simple Harmonic Motion) without a force acting on it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, harmonic-oscillator

I thought that if we take a body which is performing Simple Harmonic Motion and take its reflection on a wall. Now we observe the reflection on the wall and so we can say the reflection is performing SHM without a force acting on it.

Is it right? Or there is something wrong in it

Please also give suitable Examples if possible.

Comment: Do you consider a reflection to be a "body"?

Comment: I meant i am observing it

Answer (score 3):

The motion of SHM is given by $x(t)=A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$. Therefore, the acceleration is $\ddot x(t)=-\omega^2A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$, and the net force by Newton's second law is $F=\ddot x(t)=-m\omega^2A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$. So no, you cannot have SHM without a net force

Comment: Thank You Very Much @BioPhysicist

Answer (score 1):

It is even easier than that: just voluntarily take a pen and paper, and draw a sine curve. No force involved!

But, joking apart, force is called the thing that depends linearly on displacement and drives a mass onto a simple harmonic motion in time. If you are willing to deviate from that definition, anything becomes possible, including fairies and elves.

Comment: Thank You Very Much @Oliver for the Answer 
Understood it